# What are opportunities available and skills needed for career in GIS?

Tags: career

I am currently doing my MS software engineering. I am very much interested in GIS. I would like to know about the various opportunities available in this field and also the skills that I will have to acquire to enter into this field. I would like it to be software related.

Answer (score 5):

A quick archive search led me to these helpful questions which discuss about how can one build a GIS Career:

1. [Seeking GIS career advice?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9408/career-advice-needed)
2. [Switching career from web application to GIS developer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/getting-a-gis-position)
3. [How to get started on a GIS Programming Career?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4346/how-to-get-started-on-a-gis-programming-career)
4. [Transitioning from programmer to mapper?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44390/so-i-am-a-programmer-what-do-i-do-to-become-a-mapper)
5. [What are useful websites for scouting GIS related jobs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/gis-jobs-online)
6. [Switching career from GIS Technician/Analyst to GIS Web Map Developer/Programmer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/professionally-how-did-you-make-the-jump-from-gis-technician-analyst-to-gis-web)

So depending on your objectives you can choose to move ahead with your career.